# Prevent CSS & Javascript from being load - WebView

Tags: java

Currently I have a news website that I display in a webview in my android application. But the performance of the webview is bad and I want to improve it by blocking css and js. Is there any simple way I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For css you can use conditional media queries for different screen sizes (although css shouldn't cause much performance issues unless you use transitions and all other fancy stuff)

For javascript, you could add conditional checks for the device as well.
You can reference this question which I find answers it pretty well

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)